# TypeLite issue with generics and Enums?

Tags: .net, typescript, typelite

So I've got lots of .Net libraries/classes that I'd like to generate typescript definitions for. Typescript is great! I tried it with simple examples and it does work perfectly. The only issue I'm facing is that a combination that I have does not work with it. Here's how it doesnt work:

```
[TsClass]
public class Bob<T>
{
    public MyTestEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    public string TestString { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[TsEnum]
public enum MyTestEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

The problem is that I cannot have the combination of generics `<T>` and `Enum` in the same place. In order for it to work, i need to take out either one of them.

This is the error it gives me when I run it:

```
Error   17  Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.AddEnum(TsEnum tsEnum) in C:\___PROJECTS___\TypeLITE\TypeLite\TsModelBuilder.cs:line 98
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.Add(Type clrType, Boolean includeReferences) in C:\___PROJECTS___\TypeLITE\TypeLite\TsModelBuilder.cs:line 83
   at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.Add(Assembly assembly) in C:\___PROJECTS___\TypeLITE\TypeLite\TsModelBuilder.cs:line 108
   at TypeLite.Net4.TypeScriptFluentExtensions.ForLoadedAssemblies(TypeScriptFluent ts) in C:\___PROJECTS___\TypeLITE\TypeLite.Net4\TypeScriptFluentExtensions.cs:line 16
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingBDE10CD05B2CB4C5419DB79DDF5BA5BA06D673F55FF952439E5971D4E1F394085E3B6D99DC6D1E992221FAC06D0692FFD83BE54FE5AF6A567A491DF31AE26472.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() ..\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt
```

The fact that I'm not doing anything with generics is irrelevant (I'm just trying to make it work!)

I'd appreciate if you know of a workaround or if you can introduce another utility similar to it that is capable of doing such thing.

I've already reported this issue to the developers (hopefully Lukas address it sometime soon): https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issue/41/issue-with-generics-and-enums

Comment: Maybe open an issue over at https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issues ?

Comment: @IngoBürk thanks for reminding me! I just created the issue: https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/issue/41/issue-with-generics-and-enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Paul O'Neill](https://bitbucket.org/pablissimo), this bug is fixed in the [latest release (0.9.1.8)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeLite/0.9.1.8)

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas and Paul! I'll give it a try on Monday :)